# How to estimate data accuracy based on a sample?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, accuracy

I have a moderate size dataset (~100k rows), with a flag ("Y"/"N") for each row.
I would like to estimate the accuracy of this flag by checking whether it is correct for a subset of rows (chosen at random).

Checking all rows is not an option, since it is a time consuming process that cannot be automated.

Of course finding a wrong flag (e.g. by having "Y" in the dataset and finding out that it should actually be "N") means that the accuracy cannot be 100%, but:

1. how can I estimate the accuracy based on a sample?
2. assuming that I check $n$ values (out of $N$, with $n<<N$) and they are all correct, how do I express (statistically) how much "confident" I am that the accuracy is $100\%$?

---

Edit:
For point 2, I thought of setting up a [Chi-squared test for categorical data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data). The null-hypothesis $H_0$ would be that the "actual flag" and the flag written in the data are independent (i.e. $0\%$ accuracy of the flag).
Let's assume I am checking a random sample of size $n$ out of $N$ and find no mistake, so that the contingency table for $F_o$ and $F_d$ (respectively the observed flag and the flag obtained from the data) is the following:

$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
        & F_o=Y   & F_o=N       & \mathrm{Sum}          \\ \hline
F_d=Y & n r & 0             & n r     \\ \hline
F_d=N & 0         & n (1-r) & n (1-r) \\ \hline
\mathrm{Sum}      & n  r & n  (1-r) & n             \\ \hline
\end{array}
$

The $\chi^2$ is then just $n$. For one degree of freedom and $n=10$ I get a $p$-value of $0.001$, more than enough to reject the hypothesis of $0\%$ accuracy.

I consider this solution not satisfactory for two reasons:

- It is not very useful to reject the null-hypotesis of independence (that is, $0\%$ accuracy of the flag). I would rather test the hypothesis of $100\%$ accuracy
- The formula is counterintuitive:

  - it does not depend on the total number of rows $N$: for $n=N$ the accuracy of the data can be determined exactly
  - I don't understand intuitively why I need only $10$ observations of a large dataset to basically rule out the possibility that the flag is inaccurate: if e.g. the value "Y" occurs very rarely in the data, I expect a larger sample to be needed.

Comment: This sounds like a proportion test: either you got the right label (1) or the wrong label (0), and then some kind of confidence interval for that proportion. Does that sound right?

Comment: Look into Laplace’s rule of succession: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession. For the case where you don’t have 100%, does a proportion test make sense?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a proportion test: either you got the right label (1) or the wrong label (0), and then you want to calculate the proportion of 1s with some kind of confidence interval.

When you get all 1s, that puts you in an awkward situation where the is not variability. Laplace has a “rule of succession” where you take that variation-free sample and add a 1 and a 0 to it.